# How to leave the values already selected inside the Select and MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am a beginner in ReactJS and I have a problem with Selects. I have a `Select` that renders some plants and bees with `MenuItem`.

What I need is that Select already comes with some values marked in the list of `bees` and `plants`.

If the user clicks on New Property the selects are blank, but the user clicks on any property to edit, then the selects must be marked with checked.

I hope I managed to explain it correctly. Here's my code I put into [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-modal-working-gkjwh?file=/src/App.js)

Here's the simulation of my bee database:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "bee-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Africanizada (Apis mellifera)"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "bee-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Abelha-cachorro, Arapuá, Irapuá (Trigona spinipes)"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "bee-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Andorinha, Benjoi (Scaptotrigona polysticta)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the simulation of my plant database:

```js
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "plant-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Cana-de-açucar"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "plant-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Citros"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "plant-databases",
      "attributes": {
        "species-name": "Eucalipto"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the simulation of my properties database:

```js
  {
    "id": "45",
    "type": "properties",
    "attributes": {
      "farmer-name": "João Galli",
      "name": "Nova Propriedade",
      "address": "Rua teste",
      "total-planted-area": "100",
      "total-forest-area": "40",
      "apiaries-in-use": 20,
      "plants": [
        [
          {
            "id": 46,
            "kind": "Cana-de-açucar"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "accepted-bees": [
        [
          {
            "id": 46,
            "kind": "Africanizada (Apis mellifera)"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the select has `[Object object]` instead of the actual label.

If so, the problem is that the dropdown expects to get an array of strings for the `value` prop. Means that `beeSelect` should be an array of string, but it's actually an array of (array of) of bees

e.g.

```
"accepted-bees": [
  [
    {
      "id": 46,
      "kind": "Africanizada (Apis mellifera)"
    }
  ]
]
```

So, the `.map` should looks a bit different

```
const _selectedBees = item.attributes["accepted-bees"].map((bee) => bee[0].kind);
```

(Same goes to the plants)

https://codesandbox.io/s/edit-modal-working-forked-of675?file=/src/features/components/dialog-property/DialogProperty.jsx:1580-1673

Notes:

1. Why `accepted-bees` is an array of arrays if anyway it has only one item (the child array)
2. There is not point of doing `.map((bee) => bee)`. It returns the same value it gets.

Comment: Hey Mosh, that's works perfectly for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck.